# Is there a a predefined way to skip calculations that result in Nothing?

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I have a these three functions

```
a :: Int -> Maybe Int
a i = if i < 100 then Just i else Nothing

b :: Int -> Maybe Int
b i = if i < 50 then Just i else Nothing

c :: Int -> Maybe Int
c i = if i > 0 then Just i else Nothing
```

And I want to chain them together so that when the result of one function results in a `Nothing` the input of that function is returned instead.

I can achieve this with this function:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

e :: Int -> [Int -> Maybe Int] -> Int
e i [] = i
e i (f:fs) = e (fromMaybe i $ f i) fs
```

-

```
*Main> e 75 [a,b,c]
75
```

Is there an existing function, Monad instance, or other way in the base libraries that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: It should be clear that you can't do this in general, because the input and output types may vary. You can write a function of type `(a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a` but not `(a -> Maybe b) -> a -> b`

Comment: I'd first turn `[Int -> Maybe Int]` into `[Int -> Int]` using `fromMaybe` as you did. After that, I'd compose the list of endos.

Comment: `foldr1 (>=>) [a, b, c]`

Comment: @AlexanderVoidExRuchkin That has a different semantics from `\i -> e i [a,b,c]` (where `e` is defined above in the question).

Comment: `e = fromMaybe 75 . foldr1 (>=>) [a,b,c]`, though.

Comment: `e = \i es -> fromMaybe i $ foldr (\fn fns -> fns >=> liftA2 (<|>) fn return) pure es i`, and it actually generalizes quite nicely: `\i es -> foldr (\fn fns -> fns >=> liftA2 (<|>) fn return) pure es i` works for any `(Foldable f, Alternative m) => f (b -> m b)`.

Comment: I hope your real `a`, `b`, and `c` are more complicated, or else you could just write `e = const` and be done with it.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, this is just a minimal example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment above -- this approach is not too different from the code the OP posted.

We first define how to turn a function `a -> Maybe a` into `a -> a`, substituting the input for `Nothing`.

```
totalize :: (a -> Maybe a) -> (a -> a)
totalize f x = fromMaybe x (f x)
```

Then, we exploit the above: we make every function "total" (meaning no-`Nothing`s), wrap it as an `Endo`, then we compose the list of endomorphisms (`mconcat` is composition in the `Endo` monoid).

```
e :: [a -> Maybe a] -> a -> a
e = appEndo . mconcat . map (Endo . totalize)
```

or even (as suggested below)

```
e :: Foldable t => t (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
e = appEndo . foldMap (Endo . totalize)
```

Comment: `e = appEndo . foldMap (Endo . totalize)`?

Comment: You can also do it without the `Endo` abstraction: `compose = foldr (.) id; e = compose . map totalize`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can create a `a -> a` from a `a -> Maybe a`:

```
repair :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
repair f x = fromMaybe x (f x)
```

Afterwards, you can just combine `(.)` and `repair`:

```
andThen :: (a -> Maybe a) -> (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
andThen f g = repair g . repair f
```

But there's no library function for that, since there is no general way to get a value out of a `Monad`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the maybe monad?

```
*Main> let f x = a x >>= b >>= c >> return x
*Main> f 1
Just 1
*Main> f 100
Nothing
*Main>
```

Then if the result is Nothing we can get to your desired end state with `fromMaybe` (or just `maybe` and `id`, same thing):

```
*Main> let g x = maybe x id (f x)
*Main> g 100
100
```

Comment: This does something different from the OP code. The OP code, when `a x` returns `Nothing`, feeds `x` to `b`. Monadic chaining does not do that.